# Viewing .ecw-file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ecw

I have got a .ecw-file that I want to somehow import into QGIS 1.8.0.

Is there a plugin that I can install that can help me do this or is there another way?

The .ecw-file contains raster data.

Comment: See, please: http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/ecw/

Comment: A google search for QGIS ECW should have got you to http://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/adding-ecw-support-in-qgis/

Comment: I found the second link and then I tried to follow the intructions, but I don't understand what to do after I copied the files?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you stick to the old QGIS 1.8.

On Windows, the standalone 32bit QGIS 2.0.1 already has ecw support included. If you use the OSGEO4W setup programme, you have to go to `Advanced Install`, and activate the `gdal-ecw` package. But I assume it is activated as dependency by default if you select qgis.

If you use OSGEO4W64W, the `gdal-ecw` package has to be selected manually.

Comment: I still use 1.8 because it is compatible to another plugin that I use, and that don't work on later versions at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need a GDAL with a [ecw driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html) compiled in. You can download the [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) which contains precompiled GDAL tools and providing this driver. 
If you have the possibility to write programs you can download the [ECW-SDK](http://download.intergraph.com/?ProductName=ERDAS%20ECW/JPEG2000%20SDK) from Intergraph.

As you see in the discussion below with Luke: Use the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) instead of FWTools (it's deprecated). ...the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) & GIS Internals include the ECW/JP2 and MrSID drivers. The ECW/JP2 SDK version in both is the latest (v5.0) which is far better than the buggy old 3.3 ECW SDK from 2006 in FWTools.

Comment: Please don't recommend FWTools, it is waaay out of date and is [no longer being updated](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries).  The GDAL/OGR version in FWTools is 1.7 from 2010...  Use the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/) GDAL binaries instead.

Comment: Does OSGeo4W have all the propietary drivers like FWTools?

Comment: Yes, both OSGeo4W & GIS Internals include the ECW/JP2 and MrSID drivers.  The ECW/JP2 SDK version in both is the latest (v5.0) which is far better than the buggy old 3.3 ECW SDK from 2006 in FWTools.